# Looking for specific router / access point brand

Tags: wifi, router

Several weeks or months ago I read a discussion, probably on Hacker News, and in it somebody recommended a router that fixed all his router problems. Reception was excellent, and it had an option to configure guest access on a separate network, secure from the rest, without much effort.

I don't remember the name of the brand. I believe it had U and Q in it, but I'm not sure. The router itself was round and white, like the Engenius, but as I remember it without the leds. Pricing was about 80 euros for the basic model, and there were pro versions for about 240 euros.

[image: Engenius router]

Do you have any idea which router I'm referring to? It could even be Engenius, but I don't find anything about the guest network setup in the reviews.

Comment: This question should be changed. You can ask us which router is a good buy instead.

Comment: @PeterZhu I disagree. The required product in question is very specific and defined as best as possible.

Comment: @PeterZhu - I've updated the title. I want to know this specific brand name.

Comment: So should we have an [indentify-this-hardware] tag? KIDDING! (for anyone familiar with the identify-this issues)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your picture, and description involving "U" and "Q", it sounds like you are thinking of a product from [Ubiquiti Networks](https://www.ubnt.com/). There was a very detailed article about them on [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2015/10/review-ubiquiti-unifi-made-me-realize-how-terrible-consumer-wi-fi-gear-is/) last October.

The only issue is, they don't have have a router that looks similar to your image. There are [Access Points](https://www.ubnt.com/products/#all/wireless) though.

One of the ones that Ars reviewed was the [UniFi AP AC Pro](https://www.ubnt.com/unifi/unifi-ap-ac-pro/). You can get this [directly from Ubiquiti](https://store.ubnt.com/unifi/unifi-ac-pro.html) (when it isn't sold out) for $150.

[image: Unifi AP AC Pro - Source: Ars Technica http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2015/10/review-ubiquiti-unifi-made-me-realize-how-terrible-consumer-wi-fi-gear-is/]

Comment: Spot on! Thank you very much! Round, white, no leds, and you're right about it not being a router but an access point.